# How are points re-calculated when changing leagues?

Tags: starcraft-2

When you are promoted leagues, your points get reset. If you had 500 points in bronze, when you are promoted to silver, you might now have 400 points in silver.

How is this new score calculated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [TeamLiquid](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=183626), your points in the new league are:

```
Rating Change
Consistently, we are seeing that people promoted into Master league are 
assigned new ratings equal to 73 + spent bonus pool. 

EDIT: This was confirmed to occur for all leagues, not just Master. 
It was simply more evident due to the mass promotions that occurred 
during the first day of Master league.
```

Comment: How can you tell how much bonus pool you've used?

Comment: @tenfour Per http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Battle.net_Leagues, you get 0.5 bonus pool points per hour, or 12 per day.  So, max bonus pool is # of days since start of season * 12.  What you've used would be the difference between your current and the max.